# Sub-module can't be imported while using pytest

Tags: python, import, module, package, pytest

i have a project with the following layout:

```
/src
   /mypckg
      __init__.py
      calibration.py
      _const.py
   /tests
      test_calibration.py
   conftest.py
```

in my test file im importing my `calibration` module:

```
from mypkg import calibration
```

at the same time, my `calibration` module imports my `_const` modules, which contains all my constants:

```
import _const
```

my `__init__.py` file contains the following imports:

```
## __init__ file
from . import calibration
from . import _const
```

now, when i run `pytest` from the test folder, it finds my `calibration` module, but it gives me this error

```
...\mypckg\calibration.py:7: in <module>
    import _const
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_const'
```

my `calibration` module apparently cant find the `_const` module, but if i run `python calibration.py`from my package directory, it runs perfectly. the problem is when i try to run a function from the `calibration` module inside my test file.

if i import the `_const` module into my  `calibration` module the following way, my test works perfectly:

```
from mypckg import _const
# or from . import _const
```

but if i import it this way, when i run `python calibration.py` it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calibration.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import _const
ImportError: cannot import name '_const'
```

i tried to google my problem but didn't find anything similar, where the sub-modules cant be loaded from a test file. any idea why this behavior and how can fix it?

Comment: you should run `python -m mypckg.calibration` not `python calibration.py` -- this will be consistent with how a _package_ works (and how pytest will import your code)

Comment: Running the tests from the `src` dir is the most obvious and easy solution. If you really need to descend into `tests`, you either adjust the `sys.path` via `PYTHONPATH=..`, or write a setup script and install the project in development mode once via `python setup.py develop` or `pip install --editable .`